# most of that or most of them or most of it

Tags: grammar, agreement

I happened to read the following sentence in ‘Poached’ by Stuart Gibbs, which deals with coalas.
They(Coalas) rest sixteen to eighteen hours a day and spend most of that unconscious. 
But I wonder whether the word ‘that’ is grammatically correct, for I think that ‘most of them(the resting hours)’ is correct.
Would you grammarians teach me whether it is grammatically correct or not?

Comment: Do you mean koalas?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's fine.

> They spend most of that <sup>i.e. time devoted to resting</sup> unconscious.

Those hours allocated to resting may be understood by the speaker as a *contiguous stretch or span*, hence *that* rather than *them*.

That is not to say that one could not write "them":

> They spend most of them <sup>i.e. those hours devoted to resting</sup> unconscious.

Both are grammatical.